# Failed to re-set a DelegateCommand in IEventAggregator?

Tags: c#, wpf, prism

Suppose:

```
public DelegateCommand Cmd { get; private set; }

public ViewModel(IEventAggregtor ea)
{
    _ea = ea;

    Cmd = new DelegateCommand(() => Console.WriteLine("old!!"));

    ea.GetEvent<TestEvent>().Subscribe(() => NewingCmd());
}

private void NewingCmd()
{
    Cmd = new DelegateCommand(() => Console.WriteLine("new!!"));
}
```

Expected:
Before event publish, output be "old!!", while after publishing, also means `NewingCmd`, output be "new!!".

But both before and after the `NewingCmd`, the output is "old!!".

So can I change the `DelegateCommand` when I receive the publish?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, so when assigning a new `DelegateCommand` to `Cmd`, the bindings will not get notified of a change and are not updated. Simply derive from Prism's `BindableBase` like below. See [Implementing INotifyPropertyChanged](https://prismlibrary.com/docs/wpf/legacy/Implementing-MVVM.html#implementing-inotifypropertychanged) in the documentation.

```
public class ViewModel : BindableBase
{
   private DelegateCommand _cmd;

   public DelegateCommand Cmd
   {
      get => _cmd;
      private set => SetProperty(ref _cmd, value);
   }

   public ViewModel(IEventAggregtor ea)
   {
      _ea = ea;

      Cmd = new DelegateCommand(() => Console.WriteLine("old!!"));

      ea.GetEvent<TestEvent>().Subscribe(() => NewingCmd());
   }

   private void NewingCmd()
   {
      Cmd = new DelegateCommand(() => Console.WriteLine("new!!"));
   }
}
```

Comment: Ok thank you, that works! But it raises my confusion: why the `private` setter is able to raise property changed?

Comment: @Becks723 The private setter does not raise property changed, it is the `SetProperty` method. See its source code [here](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/342689ba9a10e511418943438d0f5c57534ca623/src/Prism.Core/Mvvm/BindableBase.cs#L30). It first checks, if the existing and new value of `_cmd` are equal and if they are not, it sets the new value and raises the property changed method. A little bit of magic happens with the `CallerMemberName` attribute. If you do not pass the `propertyName` explicitly, it will be set to the name of the caller, here `Cmd`.

Comment: @Becks723 Here is the link to the documentation of [`CallerMemberName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.callermembernameattribute?view=net-5.0).

Comment: @Becks723 also, _anyone_ can raise `PropertyChanged`, the setter of a property, the setter of another property (to notify that a dependent property changes) or a command, for example. In fact, only for the most trivial "field-on-steroids"-properties, the setter is the only one who raises the event...